# Rename files if not the current file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am quite new to bash scripting. I am trying to write a line which searches for all files with a particular name, and renames them, except for the currently running script.

Here is what I have so far:

`find $1 -name thescript.sh -exec /bin/bash -c 'test \'"$(readlink -f "$0")" = {}\' || mv {} \$\(dirname {}\)/thescript0.sh' \; || true`

Here is a brief explanation of how that works in my head:

- Determine the absolute path to the currently running script using `readlink`
- For all files `{}` named `thescript.sh` and in some subdirectory of `$1`:

  - Test if the resulting absolute path is equal to the file `{}`
  - If the test fails (i.e. they are not equal):

    - Determine the directory of the file `{}`
    - Move the file `{}` to a file under the same directory but with name `thescript0.sh`
- Always return true

A few notes:

- `$1` the first argument to the script is the base directory for the renaming
- Because I want to use "or" (`||`) within an `exec` clause, I followed some answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55636/bash-can-i-do-find-exec-this-that) and started a new shell with a quoted command within which I could use `||`, so that the shell didn't think this operator is part of the parent command. The quoted command starts from `test` and ends at `thescript0.sh`
- `readlink` is in a subshell because the result of `readlink` is passed to `test`
- I used escaped quotes for the `test` because otherwise I thought the shell will think the first quote is actually the terminator of the previous single quote (which started the quoted command)
- I also escaped the subshell, not sure if this is correct (I haven't got that far yet) because I want the subshell to be executed as part of the quoted command based on the output of `find`, rather than be executed at the beginning (when it won't have an output to work on yet)
- If the test failed (which is expected for most cases) then I don't want the whole command to return false (not sure if it would) so that's why I put `|| true` at the end

The error I am getting is:

`` line 15: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'' ``

I cannot find any mismatching quotes at the moment; there is only a single pair of unescaped quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes don't accept any escape sequences, not even `\'`. To include a single quote inside a single quoted string, you have to leave and re-enter:

```
echo 'What'"'"'s wrong?'
echo 'Oh, it'\''s nothing.'
```

Additional notes:

- `$0` won't be expanded inside of single quotes.
- `find`'s exit code is unrelated to the results of `-exec`, so `|| true` isn't needed.
- For maximum safety it's best to pass `{}` to bash as an argument rather than embedding it in the script. That way whitespace and other special characters won't trip bash up.
- Always quote variable expansions in case they contain whitespace or wildcards.

My recommended update with all of the above taken into consideration:

```
find "$1" -name thescript.sh -exec bash -c 'test "$1" == "$2" || mv "$2" "$(dirname "$2")"/thescript0.sh' bash "$(readlink -f "$0")" {} \;
```

(I haven't tested it so hopefully you get the gist even if I made some typos.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain why it's not necessary to escape the subshell constructs in `$(dirname "$2")`, as I did? I would have thought that as it stands, bash would execute that subshell once and pass the result of it into the quoted command, which would be wrong. Similarly I would have thought that `$0` would be expanded inside of the single quotes because it is inside of a subshell that would be looked at before the single quoted string and the result of the former passed to the latter. Does the subshell work differently inside single quotes?

Comment: As far as parsing goes, ignore that there's a subshell. All the outer bash shell sees is a `find` command with a bunch of arguments. An argument with single quotes is not subject to interpolation, so everything inside is passed unmodified to the `find` command. That single quoted string is left alone by the outer shell and only interpreted by the sub-shells. If it used double quotes then it *would* be subject to parsing by the outer shell, but as I say in the third bullet, it's best to avoid that.